# MATLAB code into JAVA 3 dimensional arrays within for loops

Tags: java, arrays, matlab, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have the following code within a MATLAB programme which creates three 3-dimensional arrays within for loops, I am trying to replicate this within my JAVA programme.

The MATLAB code is as follows:

```
for j = 1 : J
    for k = 1 : K

    A(j,:,k) = VariableA * ArrayB
    B(j,:,k) = VariableA ./ ArrayB
    AB(j,:,k) = A.*B

    end
 end
```

Within JAVA I have initialised the arrays that will be used via the code:

```
  double [][][] A = new double [(int) (J)][(int) (N+1)][(int)(K)];
  double [][][] B = new double [(int) (J)][(int) (N+1)][(int)(K)];
  double [][][] AB = new double [(int) (J)][(int) (N+1)][(int)(K)];
```

Please note all variables are defined prior to this section of code in both the MATLAB and JAVA programme. Also VariableA is a defined value i.e. 10 and ArrayB is a 1-dimensional row array i.e. [1 2 3 4 5 6 7].

The code I used in JAVA to create A (I used the same method for B and AB) is:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++)
         for ( int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
             for (int k = 0; k < A.length; k++)

                 A[j][i][k] = (ArrayB[j] * VariableA);

                  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(A));
```

However the above code only works for the first few values. The output is as follows:

```
 [[[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]]
```

Any help, ideas or pointers will be most appreciated as I have no idea where it is going wrong, the first 6 values are what would be expected throughout, but the array would also be expected to be separated into individual arrays as a 3-d array is an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Just for starters, your loops are wrong. Your first loop iterates from 0 to A.length, which is fine, but your next loop also iterates from 0 to A.length, which is wrong, as the second level of your multidimensional array is of a different size.

Try instead:

```
for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++)
         for ( int i = 0; i < A[j].length; i++)
             for (int k = 0; k < A[j][i].length; k++)
```

Comment: Thank you. The values are now consistent throughout the array. However when it is printed into the console it appears as [[[ 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 ]]] i.e. the matrices are not shown individually. Any ideas why this is? Thanks again though!

Comment: At first guess, I'd say your values for 'N+1' and 'K' used as the size of the other dimensions are actually both 1, but impossible to say without seeing the rest of your code and knowing what all those values are.

Comment: Could you please give me a brief explanation on the code you have provided, i.e. what the A[j].length and A[j][i].length mean as the results are now producing individual arrays but not in the way I would expect. The values of the first column of all arrays is stored as an array by itself rather than it producing an array of 1:N+1 columns values.

Comment: In java, a multidimensional array is literally an array whose elements are in turn arrays. When you define double A[][][] = new double[X][Y][Z], then the object A is an array of X elements. Each of those elements is in turn an array of Y elements, and then again each of those is an array of Z elements which are your numbers.

Comment: So A[j].length  - the value of A[j] is in itself an array, and you're asking for the number of objects in that array. As it was defined as a multidimensional array, you do know that each of those arrays is of length (N+1) as defined in your code, but it is possible that they could all be of different lengths.